# Nextflow multiple inputs with different number of files

Tags: nextflow

I'm trying to input two channels. However, the seacr_res_ch2 has 4 files, bigwig_ch3 has 5 files which contain a control and 4 samples. So I was trying to run the following process to compute the peak center.
When I ran this process I have got this error:  unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'

```
process compute_matrix_peak_center {

    input:
    set val(sample_id), file(seacr_bed) from seacr_res_ch2
    set val(sample_id), file(bigwig) from bigwig_ch3

    output:
    set val(sample_id), file("${sample_id}.peak_centered.mat.gz") into peak_center_ch

    script:
    """

    "computeMatrix reference-point \
        -S ${bigwig} \
        -R ${seacr_bed} \
        -a 1000 \
        -b 1000 \
        -o ${sample_id}.peak_centered.mat.gz \
        --referencePoint center \
        -p 10

    """
}
```

Comment: You have an extra `"` on the first line of your script block. I.e. `"computeMatrix` should just be `computeMatrix`

Comment: Can you edit your question to show us your inputs? What is the output of `seacr_res_ch2.view()` and what is the output of `bigwig_ch3.view()` when you run your script?

Answer (score 1):

Likely the input files are not *file* objects. Try replacing the `file` in the declaration with `path`, eg:

```
input:
set val(sample_id), path(seacr_bed) from seacr_res_ch2
set val(sample_id), path(bigwig) from bigwig_ch3
```

Check the documentation for details https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#input-of-type-path

Answer (score 1):

Your input block declares twice a value called `sample_id`. There's no guarantee that these values will be the same if the value is derived from two (or more) channels. One value will simply clobber the other(s). You'll need to [join()](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#join) these channels first:

```
input:
set val(sample_id), file(seacr_bed), file(bigwig) from seacr_res_ch2.join(bigwig_ch3)
```